# How can I load only specific values of a column in a table to a combo box

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, jcombobox

How can I load only specific values of column in a table to a combo box(As an example let's say that there is a column named "exp_date" in warranty table.I want to get the warrandy_id to the combo box where the  exp_date equals to today's date).

Answer (score 3):

- Assuming that your TableModel holds a List of objects of a class,
- You could simply add those same objects to your JComboBox's model (an AbstractListModel or DefaultComboBoxModel which ever works best for you).
- Then use a custom cell renderer (ListCellRenderer) that only displays the column (property) of interest.

For details, please see the [JComboBox Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)